# Codeigniter Batch Process update previous record status

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have MySQL Database in Codeigniter framework that is used to manage items in a store. Item issuing & verifying status are maintained in the following tables.

### store_update_stock Table

```
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
| update_stock_id | old_row_id | supplier | order_status | transfer_status |    user    |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
|             561 |          0 |        3 | issue        | Approved        | Spsstrope1 |
|             563 |          0 |        3 | issue        | Approved        | Spsstrope1 |
|             566 |          0 |        3 | issue        | Approved        | Spsstrope1 |
|             568 |          0 |        3 | issue        | Approved        | Spsstrope1 |
|               . |            |          |              |                 |            |
|               . |            |          |              |                 |            |
|               . |            |          |              |                 |            |
|             581 |        563 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             582 |        561 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             583 |        568 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             584 |        566 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
```

### store_update_stock_details Table

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
| update_stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | r_qty | ap_qty | is_qty | unit_price |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
|                    1920 |             581 |    5 |   0 |     1 |      1 |      0 |          0 |
|                    1921 |             581 |    5 |   0 |     2 |      2 |      0 |          0 |
|                    1922 |             582 |    5 |   0 |     1 |      1 |      0 |          0 |
|                    1923 |             583 |   37 |   0 |     5 |      5 |      0 |          0 |
|                    1924 |             584 |    1 |   0 |     1 |      1 |      0 |          0 |
|                    1925 |             584 |   70 |   0 |     1 |      1 |      0 |          0 |
|                       . |                 |      |     |       |        |        |            |
|                       . |                 |      |     |       |        |        |            |
|                       . |                 |      |     |       |        |        |            |
|                    1990 |             581 |    5 |  -1 |     0 |      0 |      1 |      66.00 |
|                    1991 |             581 |    5 |  -2 |     0 |      0 |      2 |      77.00 |
|                    1992 |             582 |    5 |  -1 |     0 |      0 |      1 |      77.00 |
|                    1993 |             583 |   37 |  -5 |     0 |      0 |      5 |       4.04 |
|                    1994 |             584 |    1 |  -1 |     0 |      0 |      1 |       7.50 |
|                    1995 |             584 |   70 |  -1 |     0 |      0 |      1 |      16.50 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------+--------+--------+------------+
```

The two tables are joined by "update_stock_id". When performing item requests', the order_status bacame "issues" and transfer_status became "Approved" in the store_update_stock table and inserted relevant records to the store_update_stock_details table.

When performing issues of items, new records were added to the both tables related to the approved records. And order_status became "verifyIssue" and transfer_status became "Verified".

Relevant part of my Controller as follows :

```
public function verifyItemReqFromHD()       
    {
        $this->checkPermissions('edit', 'issueApprovedItem');
        $bc = array(array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Item Request From HD'));
        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Item Request From HD', 'bc' => $bc); 

        $this->data['products'] = $this->Item_model->getProducts();                 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('item', 'Item', 'required');      

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

            $count = count($this->input->post('item_id'));
            $items = $this->input->post('item_id');
            $qts = $this->input->post('qty');           
            $unit_price = $this->input->post('unit_price'); 

            $usid = $this->input->post('update_stock_id');

            $total = 0;

            for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {
                $details[$x]['update_stock_id'] = null;
                $details[$x]['item'] = $items[$x];
                $details[$x]['qty'] = (-1)*$qts[$x];            
                $details[$x]['is_qty'] = $qts[$x]; 
                $details[$x]['unit_price'] = $unit_price[$x];               
                $details[$x]['status'] = 1;               
            }      

            $stock = array(
                'office_id' => '',
                'branch_id' => '',
                'old_row_id' => $usid,              
                'supplier' => $this->session->userdata('id_user'),
                'request_no' => '',
                'auto_no' => '',                
                'purchased_date' => '',
                'billed_date' => '',
                'user' => ucfirst($this->session->userdata('name')),
                'order_status' => 'verifyIssue',
                'transfer_status' => 'Verified',
                'status' => '1'
            );
            //dd($stock);
            if ($this->Item_model->addItemReqFromHD($stock, $details)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Successfully Issued..!!');
                redirect('item/approvedItemsToIssue');
            }

        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', validation_errors());
            $this->render('item/viewItemtoIssued', $meta, $this->data);
        }
    }
```

And model as follows :

```
function addItemReqFromHD($data,$details)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        if ($this->db->insert('store_update_stock', $data)) {
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            foreach ($details as $detail) {
                $detail['update_stock_id'] = $id;
                $this->db->insert('store_update_stock_details', $detail);
            }
        }
        $this->db->update('store_update_stock', array('transfer_status' => 'Verified'), array($id => $data['update_stock_id']));
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        if ($this->db->trans_status() === true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;        

    }
```

### Desired Output

When performing issues, I want to update order_status as "verifyIssue" & transfer_status as "Verified" in the relevant previous records. In this example the output may following :

```
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
| update_stock_id | old_row_id | supplier | order_status | transfer_status |    user    |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
|             561 |          0 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             563 |          0 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             566 |          0 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             568 |          0 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|               . |            |          |              |                 |            |
|               . |            |          |              |                 |            |
|               . |            |          |              |                 |            |
|             581 |        563 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             582 |        561 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             583 |        568 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
|             584 |        566 |        3 | verifyIssue  | Verified        | Spsstrope1 |
+-----------------+------------+----------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
```

In my model I used the following line to do that.

```
$this->db->update('store_update_stock', array('transfer_status' => 'Verified'), array($id => $data['update_stock_id']));
```

But didn't get the desired output. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the update query is performed against `store_update_stock`, 'update_stock_id' is an **undefined** index in `$data` array.

When you traceback to where `$data` is passed, you find this to be the $stock array that is declared in the controller.

Now, the `update_stock_id` are set in each `$detail` array after the items are inserted in `store_update_stock` table.

This is the part of your code that does this.

```php
foreach ($details as $detail) {
   $detail['update_stock_id'] = $id;
   $this->db->insert('store_update_stock_details', $detail);
}
```

I suggests to get all the ids into an array and use that in the where clause of the update query for the `store_update_stock` table.

```php
function addItemReqFromHD($data,$details)
{
    $updateStockIds = [];
    $this->db->trans_start();
    if ($this->db->insert('store_update_stock', $data)) {
        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
        $updateStockIds[] = $id;
        # ...
    }
    $this->db->where_in('update_stock_id', $updateStockIds);
    $this->db->update(
        'store_update_stock', 
        array('order_status' => 'verifyIssue', 'transfer_status' => 'Verified')
    );
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    # ...    
}
```